# Numeral-noun number agreement - how popular it is

Tags: indo-european, numerals, georgian, plurality, agreement

I am interested in the feature of number agreement for simple cases of "several nouns" in various languages.

Some languages featuring this agreement are e.g. English or Slavic languages (I don't know if it is featured in all Indo-European). I know it is the case also in Hebrew and Arabic (as before, I don't know if this is a feature of all Euro-Asiatic) languages. In these languages you say e.g. "five apples". You use plural although the numeral already conveys the information about plurality.

In other languages like Georgian and some Ugro-Finnic languages, the plural form is not used if there is already a numeral that gives us the information about plurality. In Georgian you say "ხუთი ვაშლი", not "ხუთი ვაშლები".

My questions are:

1. How popular are these two types of languages around the world?
2. Are there any papers analyzing this feature?
3. Is there some correlation between this feature and other features of languages (e.g. Kartvelian and Ugro-Finnic languages are also agglutinating languages)

Comment: This is called *number agreement*.

Comment: Turkish nouns do not inflect for plurality when preceded by a numeric quantifier: Five cars = Beş araba (not *beş arabalar)

Comment: *The languages with redundant plural would be e.g. Indo-European and Afro-Asiatic* There is so much wrong with this sentence. 1) These are not languages. They are language families. 2) How many languages did you actually investigate to come to that conclusion? One? Two? Or all ~400 languages of IE and all ~400 of Afro-Asiatic? 3) How many different branches of these langauge families did you include? Just a single one? Or all 8 in IE and all 7 in Afr.-As.? 4) How do you even get to the assumption that plural marking is redundant?

Comment: You can see a marginal use of the non-redundant plural in English phrases like "a 2 mile distance", "a 5 pound bag".  (I don't understand the belittling comments above to your perfectly legitimate question.)

Comment: My expectation is that the line would go between inflectional languages (having typically some sort of number agreement, or as you call it _redundant plural_) and agglutinative languages which tend to not repeat functions (e.g. having the grammatical morphemes typically just on the last member of a phrase).

Comment: @Greg Lee these are not good examples because in these both cases 2 mile and 5 pound can be considered a compound adjective. On the other hand, "he spent 5 million" would in fact count.

Comment: @lemontree 1-3 I have assumed (which might wrong) that this feature would be consistent among a language family. I don't know of any Indo-European language that for a simple case of "X objects" wouldn't use the plural marking. For Afro-Asiatic I asked a friend that studies Arabic and Hebrew only. For Ugro-Finnic I consulted a person studying Mansi, Hungarian and Finnish. I don't see much information about Kartvelian languages other than Georgian.
4. I called it "redundant", because it conveys an information already conveyed by the numeral.

Comment: @zefciu Hence it is called agreement. Every agreement is, by this logic, redundant. _He goes_ is basically [**3-SG**-M] go-[**3-SG**] where _He go_ would perfectly do the job.

Comment: I have edited my question to use correct terminology and remove unjustified assumptions.

Comment: Arabic uses genitive plural nouns after the numbers 3 to 10 only. After higher numbers it uses the accusative or genitive singular.

Comment: " I don't know of any Indo-European language that for a simple case of "X objects" wouldn't use the plural marking." - In Persian all numbers are followed by singular nouns.

Comment: In Irish, numbers go wih singular nouns

Comment: Plural form is not used in Turkic languages and Japonic languages too.

Answer (score 2):

This feature or lack thereof is common enough across language families.  Besides Hungarian, Turkish and Georgian, it also occurs in Armenian, Persian and apparently Hindi, which are of course Indo-European.

But questions about popularity are very subjective as it requires us to decide what is a language and how to weight each language, for example Luxembourgish or some dialect of Bengali with far more speakers.  Moreover the way the feature works varies a bit, so the classification is not perfectly binary.

The feature is not necessarily about number in the languages mentioned above, but any modifier that implies a plural, including *much*, *many*, *some* or *a few*.  And often redundant pluralisation is theoretically allowed, but just very emphatic or otherwise marked.

In the case of Finnish and Estonian there are some nuances, in theory the form after a number is a singular form, but by the strict test they do not have the feature, the form used after *2* or *many* is different than that used after *1*.

In some cases there is simply a specific word which does not require the plural, for example Italian *qualche*.  English *nil*, *zero* and *no* also have some nuances.  In other cases there are certain scenarios which do not require the plural, so for example in English one says *fourteen stone*, in German *eine Million Euro*, one orders *zwo Bier* and *drei Stück Flammkuchen*, *viermal* if necessary.  In Slavic languages *21, 31... 101... 121...* and so on agree like *1*.  But we would not consider this to be a feature of Italian, English, German or Slavic in general.

More happily, this set of features is relatively practical to test for with machine translation.  Even if not completely reliable for each language, it can answer the question about the aggregate.

If Google Translate is to be believed, it is not really correlated with agglutination or other features like lack of gender, as it occurs in Hindi but not in Tamil.  The feature seems if anything areal and unstable, that is, it varies between closely related languages.

Comment: Can anybody find this feature in WALS?  I could not.

Answer (score 1):

In most Berber languages (In Riffian, a numeral does not agree with a noun), agreement for numerals concerns the number and the gender. The noun agrees in number with the numeral and, inversely, the numeral agrees in gender with the noun. An example from Kabyle:

yiwen n wergaz

one GEN man

one man

sen n yirgazen

two GEN men

two men

sen-t n tillawin

two-F GEN women

two women

That leads to another issue, which is the head? In Berber, numerals are included inside a genetival construction. The numeral behaves as the head of a standard genetival construction, but it agrees as a modifier (because it agrees in gender with the noun).

A discussion about this issue in WALS: https://wals.info/chapter/89

Answer (score 0):

In many languages the word-form after a numeral can be considered a separate case.

For instance, in English we say "five million" instead of "five millions". In Russian the word for million would be plural in this case, but, say, the word for "gram" would be in singular form:

> пуля весит девять грамм "bullet weights nine gram"
>
> на этой шкале нет граммов "this scale has no grams"

Some Russian linguists thus consider it a separate, "Numerative" case, which has special morphological forms for many units of measurement, soldier troop types, paired items and some vegetables.

I think, in English this usage also can be considered a morphological case, even though English is usually considered not having morphological cases in nouns.

Comment: The possessive with  's is (synchronically and diachronically) a morphological case.

Comment: @fdb no, it is a clitic:  "president and premier's duties" or "premier and president's duties" - the clitic changes place depending on the order of similar items.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to treat _five million_ as a whole as the numeral? Just like _five hundred_, not *_five hundreds_.

Comment: @the same happens with gram/grams and other nouns.

Comment: -1: this is an anecdotal evidence, not an attempt to answer the question.

Comment: Anixx, @fdb https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_possessive#Status_of_the_possessive_as_a_grammatical_case